# How to: parse a string 'mm/yyyy' into a date in PHP5.3?

Tags: parsing, date, php-5.3

I come from Java & C# worlds, and just wondering how do I parse a string formatted as `mm/yyyy` into a date in PHP 5.3.

I've tried with the following:

```
date_parse_from_format('mm/yyyy', '05/2013');
```

Then the returned array complains with errors:

```
[2] => Unexpected data found.
[5] => The separation symbol could not be found
[7] => Data missing
```

How to parse to date a string formatted as `mm/yyyy` in PHP 5.3?

---

Here is the complete `var_dump`:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2013
    [month] => 20
    [day] =>
    [hour] =>
    [minute] =>
    [second] =>
    [fraction] =>
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 3
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [2] => Unexpected data found.
            [5] => The separation symbol could not be found
            [7] => Data missing
        )

    [is_localtime] =>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'m/Y'` instead of `'mm/yyyy'`. Look at the **[date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** function for details.

```
date_parse_from_format('m/Y', '05/2013');
```

What to do next...first of all I'd use **[Object oriented style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '05/2013');

// 2013-05
echo $date->format('Y-m');

// 1369946144 UNIX timestamp
echo $timestamp = $date->format('U'); 

// 2013-05 using date(), procedural style
echo date('Y-m', $timestamp );
```

Comment: `date_parse_from_format('m/Y', '05/2013');` works flawlessly.

Comment: can you expand more by providing how to convert the returned array into a PHP date?

Comment: Yes, and definitively the object oriented style is the way to go! Thanks!